# Requirement of the problem

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I came across this problem in Axler but i don't quite understand what is required of me in this problem.

Given that $v,w\in V$. Explain Why there exists a unique $x\in V$ such that $v+3x=w$
Here $V$ is a vector space.

Am i required to provide the proof of the existence of a unique $x$ because that seems to be fairly elementary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v+3x=w \iff 3x=w-v \iff x=\frac{1}{3}(w-v)$.